# Update two different values with one AJAX response

Tags: html, ajax

I want to update two different values with one ajax-response.

```
<span id="nr1">Change this</span>
<span id="nr2">and change this</span>
```

Now I can just change one value, I do like this:

```
document.getElementById('nr1').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('nr1').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText1;
document.getElementById('nr2').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText2;
```

**** UPDATE ****
The response comes from php.
I'm totally new to JSON.

Comment: I added some links to the PHP JSON libraries in my response. There are some very good examples on the PHP site with json_encode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no responseText1 and responseText2 properties of an XMLHTTPRequest(which I assume your xmlHttp is), just responseText, so you have to return something parsable in that responseText field(like JSON). So you server may send back {"firstResponse":"value1","secondResponse":"value2"} and you can fill your fields from that JSON string. Use the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library from json.org

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
. . .
var theResponse = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
document.getElementById('nr1').innerHTML = theResponse.firstResponse;
document.getElementById('nr2').innerHTML = theResponse.secondResponse;
```

**EDIT:**
In order to craft this JSON response from PHP you should use the [PHP JSON libraries](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php). There are several examples in the [json_encode page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) that can get you started. The other code I posted(and that is posted in other responses) are all browser side javascript code.

```
$arr = array ('firstResponse'=>'value1','secondResponse'=>'value2');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Place that code into your PHP script to generate the JSON string

```
{"firstResponse":"value1","secondResponse":"value2"}
```

Then the previously posted javascript code will parse that.

Comment: I try to do like you say. I get the right response from php: {"firstResponse":"value1","secondResponse":"value2"}. But it does not print out anything in span nr1 or nr2. Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Download json2.js from json.org, http://www.json.org/json2.js  and use JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText) instead of .parseJSON(). I've been stuck with my companies internals too long.

Comment: Hm, but it does not work with åäö. Do you have any ideas how to handle that. It would be fine if i don't need to convert åäö to &aring, &auml and &ouml;

Answer (score 1):

If you trust and control the server, just return a dictionary in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for the response and use it on the client side.  So:

```
v = eval(xmlHttp.responseText);
document.getElementById('nr1').innerHTML = v['nr1']
document.getElementById('nr2').innerHTML = v['nr2']
```

Comment: Ok, not sure I get the hole picture. I use php. Can you give me an example on how the php can look?

Answer (score 0):

As already said it would make sense to return your Ajax call as a JSON Object. I recommend the more secure JSONP call (don't know if you can use any library that supports this natively).

```
// Your script returns this
callback123(
{
    "nr1" : "This is conten for nr1",
    "nr2" : "Some content for nr2"
});

// JavaScript callback looks like this
function callback123(data)
{
    for(var key in data)
        document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = data[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse

[link text](http://www.json.org/js.html)